# DotNetNuke Action Menu Error

Tags: c#, dotnetnuke

I'm using DotNetNuke 5.3. I add one menu item in `ModuleActionCollection`. Then I add this page to Module definition also. But I got this error:

> Error: is currently unavailable.
>   DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions.ModuleLoadException:
>   Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object. --->
>   System.NullReferenceException: Object
>   reference not set to an instance of an
>   object. at
>   DotNetNuke.UI.Modules.ModuleHost.LoadModuleControl()
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the `ModuleActions` property from the `IActionable` interface?  Can you attach a debugger to that property and see if the `NullReferenceException` is happening in there?  If you remove the `IActionable` interface from the module, does that get rid of the error?

Can you provide your implementation of `ModuleActions`?

Comment: its working fine...i forgot to add namesapes..thats y is not work..anyway thanks for your reply